# Smart Image size with css

Tags: css, image, resize

Rather than me going into crazy detail with my question: [Home Page Here](http://cobra.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/)

As the demo shows, when you resize the window, the images try to stay perfectly in the center of the container, as well as fitting the container **without** displaying the background.

I have one minor bug, if you resize the window vertically, it does ruin the proportions of the images by squishing them. I was wondering if anyone has any ***tricks*** to help this situation, or will I need to detect the image size compared to the window height vs proportions?

I was just trying to avoid a javascript layout.

Comment: But the proportions of the images are not ruined when I resize it vertically. They look fine.

Comment: Same here. They scale nicely for me in Chrome at least. What browser are you looking at? An alternative would be to use background images with the new `background-size` property.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Sorry @kevinamadeus, I had forgotten to actually save it with the problem I'm having, my bad, I've amended it now!

Comment: Sorry @ralph.m, I've edited the page to suit my description.

Comment: They're not a background image, they're a physical element. I can't see how this would work anyway, setting it to `background-size: contain` is close, but still not going to work because it won't 'fill' the container.

Comment: Hm, still working perfectly for me. Is this an issue in a particular browser?

Comment: It's definitely not browser specific, if you resize the window VERTICALLY, once you get to a certain point it starts to squash them. Have you cleared your browser cache? or hard refreshed?